# "For me" or "To me"

Tags: grammar, word-choice

I was watching a show and a guy picked up a rose, and he was next to a girl, so I thought he was going to say something, but he just walked away, I was kind of disappointed but here's my question:

Would he have said "Is that to me?" or "Is that for me?" and what would've been the difference if he had said one or the other?

Comment: Are you sure that your question is "would he have said..." rather than "would SHE have said..."?

Comment: @DavidWashington How is that relevant? The question is how I asked it, the guy picked up the rose, not the girl. I'd appreciate it if you just answered the question rather than think I don't know what I'm trying to ask.

Comment: The OP doesn't indicate that the guy was trying to give the rose to the girl, so he could mean **he**... but maybe the correct question is something more along the lines of *Can I have this?*

Comment: Here are some [questions asking about 'for me' and 'to me'](http://ell.stackexchange.com/search?q=for+me+to+me). Perhaps you can find some help there. The question as it stands is difficult to answer. Also, if you had a link to a video of the show, that might help us try to answer your question.

Comment: Why was the rose sitting there, available for him to pick up? Or do you mean he had "picked it up" earlier, e.g.  from a florist shop?

Answer (score 4):

*"Is that to me?"* makes no sense, so he couldn't have been going to say that. *"Is that for me?"* does make sense. For example, it could be a pick-up line where he's whimsically pretending that the girl had left the flower there as an offering to him.

But I'll also note that @David Washington's question, which you dismissed a bit abruptly I might add, was a perfectly good one. Given the scenario you described, it makes far more sense to ask about what the *girl* would have said on seeing the guy pick up the rose. I've ignored that in trying to give you an answer, but David's question was absolutely relevant.